# PHP session is empty despite being set

Tags: php, session

On form submit, the form action does its work successfully, but when I finally start a session to pass information to the "thank you" page, I get the following error:

```
A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: store_fullname
Filename: libraries/Functions.php(688) : eval()'d code
Line Number: 38
```

I'm defining about 12 session variables. Each time the error is output, the line number in the error changes.

This is how I'm creating my session. I already double checked that `$store["name"] exists.

```
session_start(); // start session
$_SESSION["store_fullname"] = $store["name"];

$url = "https://website.com/form/thanks";

header( "Location: $url" );
```

**Attempted Solutions:**

Starting session on "thank you" page. Got this error.

```
A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED
Severity: Notice
Message: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
Filename: libraries/Functions.php(688) : eval()'d code
Line Number: 4
```

Comment: you not forget start session on a `thank you` page?

Comment: Attempted that. Edited my question to include the result of this attempt @maximkou